# why does this function not fire in the __init__ method?

Tags: python

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.val.lower()
```

Why doesn't lower() operate on the contents of val in this code?

Comment: Actually it does, but you don't store the result. See what aix wrote.

Comment: Remember that strings are immutable in Python.  Nothing can change a string object -- you can only get a modified copy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
self.val = self.val.lower()
```

Or, more concisely:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val.lower()
```

To elaborate, [`lower()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) doesn't modify the string in place (it can't, since strings are immutable). Instead, it returns a copy of the string, appropriately modified.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) states it pretty clearly:

> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters [4] converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

It is because **strings are immutable**. You cannot change them in-place.

Thus, you must overwrite the value of the variable like that:

```
self.val = self.val.lower()
```

**Note:** Unless, of course, your `self.val` is not a string, but rather some mutable object that is changed in-place after calling `lower()` method. But this is not the case (you can make it the case if you have created the class of `self.val`, though).

Example of mutable object with `lower()` method changing it in-place:

```
>>> class LowerableList(list):
    def lower(self):
        for i, item in enumerate(self):
            self[i] = item.lower()

>>> a = LowerableList(['A', 'a', 'X', 'D'])
>>> a
['A', 'a', 'X', 'D']
>>> a.lower()
>>> a
['a', 'a', 'x', 'd']
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

In Python there are 2 types of function that leads to this kind of confusion. For example to sort a list you could do:

```
>>> a.sort()
```

or

```
>>> a = sorted(a)
```

first one sorts in "a", but second sorts "a" and returns new sorted list.

Comment: Then tell me what function should I use to lower the string in `self.val` instead of returning it.